# What is the correct way to link php pages?

Tags: php

Hello so I recently learned PHP and was wondering how should I link different pages to always work well and create as little inconsistencies as possible.

In my code I use either this:

```
include 'newcomment.php';
include 'menu.php';
```

or I use this type:

```
include '../MiniPost/database.php';
include '../MiniPost/newtopic.php';
```

I am sure they both are not optimal. With first one being worse as it makes me put all my php in one folder. I do not remember how I started using the second one It think I saw it somewhere on Stackoverflow the .. means root right? Few times I had issues where i put for example ../MiniPost/Forum/Forum.php and it kept giving me errors does it have anything to do the way I reference the pages?
What do you use to reference the pages and you feel is good practice to keep?

Answer (score 3):

`..` means the folder up from the current folder. `.` means the current folder.

You can work with a file in a subdirectory...

`$file = "lib/test.php";`

...or in the upper directory...

`$file = "../test.php";`

...or all of these:

`$file = "../lib/test.php";`

In some cases, it can be useful to make the path absolute from the current file. I would recommend it, because you can get problems otherwise in some cases.

`$file = dirname(__FILE__) . "/lib/test.php";`

*- or, shorter -*

`$file = __DIR__ . "/lib/test.php";`

Comment: One should always make the paths relative to current file using `__FILE__` or `__DIR__` to make sure they will be resolved to the same file regardless where the include/require chain started.

Comment: @ogondza: Yes, this chain is the problem :-) Yes, `__DIR__` is simplier. I will add it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to define a constant as the `site_root`.

You might add this into your `index.php`:

```
define('SITE_ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

And then maybe add a very basic autoloader:

```
<?php
function __autoload($class_name) {
    include SITE_ROOT . '/src/' . $class_name . '.php';
}
?>
```

The autoloader allows to work without `include` statements in your code.

Just instantiate a class: `<?php $object = new Test;?>`

The file loaded is then `SITE_ROOT.'/src/Test.php'`.

This stops spreading include/require statements throughout your code.

Answer (score 0):

Both ways are correct. The first one the file is in the same level (folder) and the second option you going a level up and start from there.

For example, you have this structure.

```
class/
class/myClass.php
category/
category/index.php
```

If you need to include myClass.php from index.php, you need to go up one level and go to class folder and call the file.

In this case,

```
Include('../class/myClass.php');
```